# On Dummit's paper

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, quintics

I have been recently reading Dummit's paper on solvability of quintic polynomials. At certain point, he mentiones that all results are valid "over any field $K$ of characteristic different from 2 and 5."

I would like to know if the real field satisfies that. Also what does it mean in order words?

Also, any elementary references on Abstract Algebra would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

One way of thinking about the characteristic of a field is it's the smallest number of times you add $1$ to itself to get back to $0$. For example, in $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, $1 + 1 = 0$, so the characteristic is $2$. For fields like $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$ where you will never get to $0$ by adding strings of $1$, we say the characteristic is $0$.

Comment: For further reference on abstract algebra, I would, well recommend "Abstract Algebra" by, well, none other than Dummit (and Foote).

Comment: Thanks! I did not understand quite well the computation done. I will read the reference. Do you mind if I ask about the complex field? Is it characteristic 0 like the real and rational?

Comment: Yes, the field of complex numbers has characteristic 0 too.